# Cloudera Manage 5.7.0, the cloudera-scm-agent fail to start,Unable to create the pidfile

Tags: java, cloudera, cloudera-cdh

[image]

I start the cloudera-scm-agent,but it is failing. I see the log from `/opt/cm-5.7.0/log/cloudera-scm-agent`. It said

```
/opt/cm-5.7.0/lib64/cmf/agent/build/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/cmf-5.7.0-py2.6.egg/cmf/parcel.py:17: DeprecationWarning: the sets module is deprecated
  from sets import Set
[06/May/2016 12:24:12 +0000] 1589 MainThread agent        INFO     SCM Agent Version: 5.7.0
Unable to create the pidfile.
```

How can I do? Please help me!

Comment: post cloudera agent logs (/var/log/cloudera-scm-agent)

Answer (score 0):

You should `mkdir /opt/cm-5.7.0/run/cloudera-scm-agent`.

Comment: But I have another problem.It is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37107364/cloudera-manage-5-7-0-yarn-sh-error-found-before-invoking-supervisord-diction . Can you help me ? Thanks.